# Django QuerySet FIlter based on previous QuerySet

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset

This may be a simple answer but after days of searching I cannot seem to figure out the correct way to achieve this.

I have a template where I want to show all the questions that are related to an assessment that has been assigned to a user. I thought that I could use the results from:

```
ResponseDetails = AssessmentResponse.objects.prefetch_related('assessment').filter(id=response_id)
```

by looking into the object and grabbing the assessment_id which I could then pass into the next query-set as a filter but I couldn't get that to work.

Problem: Because the view doesn't filter based on the assessment_id found in the AssessmentResponse model, it gives me every question in the AssessmentQuestion model.

An answer would allow me to actually have a good nights sleep trying to figure it out.

**Views**

```
def UpdateAssessmentResponse(request, response_id):
    ResponseDetails = AssessmentResponse.objects.prefetch_related('assessment').filter(id=response_id)

    QuestionList = AssessmentQuestion.objects.all()
    ChoiceList = AssessmentQuestionChoice.objects.all()
    context = {
        "ResponseDetails":ResponseDetails,
        "QuestionList":QuestionList,
        "ChoiceList": ChoiceList,
        #"ID" : ID,
    }
    return render(request, "assessment/assessment_response_update.html", context)
```

**Template**

```
    {% if QuestionList and ResponseDetails%}
      {% csrf_token %}
      {% for question in QuestionList %}
          <p> {{ question.question_text }} </p>
            {% for choice in ChoiceList %}
              {% if choice.question_id == question.pk %}
              <fieldset id="group1">
                <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label>
                </div>
              <fieldset id="group1">
              {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
      <div class="card-footer">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
      </div>
      {% else %}
          <p>There are currently no questions for this assessment.</p>
      {% endif %}
```

**Models:**

```
class AssessmentForm(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    description = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_published = models.BooleanField()
    due_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class AssessmentResponse(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    assessment = models.ForeignKey('AssessmentForm', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('assessment_response_detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    #def get_assessment_id(self):
    #    return self.assessment

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user

class AssessmentQuestionType(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.type

class AssessmentQuestionCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    assessment = models.ForeignKey('AssessmentForm', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class AssessmentQuestionSubCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    parent_category = models.ForeignKey('AssessmentQuestionCategory', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

#CHOICES_HELP_TEXT = _(u"""The choices field is only used if the question type if the question type is 'radio', 'select', or 'select multiple' provide a comma-separated list of options for this question .""")

class AssessmentQuestion(models.Model):
    question_type = models.ForeignKey('AssessmentQuestionType', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    question_text = models.TextField()
    is_required = models.BooleanField()
    category = models.ForeignKey('AssessmentQuestionCategory', on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey('AssessmentQuestionSubCategory', on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    assessment = models.ForeignKey('AssessmentForm', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

class AssessmentQuestionChoice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(AssessmentQuestion, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text

class AssessmentAnswer(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    question = models.ForeignKey('AssessmentQuestion', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    response = models.ForeignKey('AssessmentResponse', on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

Comment: Unfortunately there seems to be a lot wrong in the code you posted. In your models should the response not be related to the questions asked? Otherwise how would you know what it was referring to? An assessment should have questions (one to many) and questions should have a response (one to one) or multiple responses (one to many). You should also be using forms to post data and I suggest you look into the PEP8 style guide for python.

Comment: Yeah the code isn't the greatest but I only recently started learning Django/Python.

The AssessmentResponse model is a way for the application to assign a set of questions to a user. It doesn't contain any answers, I have added these to the original question as maybe it makes it clearer. Thanks for the response though, I will have a look at the PEP8 so i can improve my code!

Comment: Figured it out!

Objects.filter is a lazy query so it wasn't actually available to my other query-set to use as a filter. Solved it by using objects.get instead.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out! Objects.filter is a lazy query so it wasn't actually available to my other query-set to use as a filter. Solved it by using objects.get instead.